# Can't echo or create a symbolic link to a file with special characters in its name inside bash script

Tags: shell-script, quoting, command-substitution

I'm trying to create a symbolic link to files with the following naming convention:

```
.$abc$namehere.zip;1
```

As can be seen, it has the following special characters in it: . $ ;

In my bash script I have the following lines of code:

```
FILE1=`find /mydir/ -name "\.\$abc\$*namehere*.zip*" | sort -rn | head -1`
ln -s $FILE1 .
echo "$FILE1"
```

When I issue the `find` command by itself on the command line, I get a result displayed on screen of the file that I am interested in. However, when it is placed in the script above, the symbolic link command returns:

```
ln: `./.': cannot overwrite directory
```

And the echo command returns a blank line instead of the file name.

May I get some help as to how I can fix this in my script so that I could create a symbolic link to these files with special characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$()` instead of backticks:

```
FILE1=$(find /mydir/ -name "\.\$abc\$*namehere*.zip*" | sort -rn | head -1)
ln -s "$FILE1" .
echo "$FILE1"
```

The problem is that since you are enclosing your file's name in double quotes, bash is expanding it so this

```
\.\$abc\$*namehere*.zip*
```

is expanded to

```
\.namehere*.zip*
```

That's one of the many reasons why backticks are deprecated and `$()` should always be preferred.

Comment: <pre>ben@crystal:~$ echo `echo "\.\$abc\$*namehere*.zip*" `
\.namehere*.zip*
ben@crystal:~$ echo $(echo "\.\$abc\$*namehere*.zip*" )
\.$abc$*namehere*.zip*
</pre> by the way you should double quote $file on ln, on echo it doesn't matter.

Comment: @hildred yes indeed, I just copy pasted the OP's code and forgot to quote the var, thanks. I have no idea what the first part of your comment means though.

Comment: It ate the whitespace, and the backquotes, which makes it hard to understand. To test the code I used echo to print the results of backtick and $() expansion of the double quoted string, and back ticks leave the backslash in front of the dot.

Comment: `bash` should not be doing this thing. I think this is either a bug in `bash` or a deliberate departure from portability. The backslash is to be treated literally within backquoted command substitution - which should get eaten by `"quotes"` as you say - *unless* followed by `$` `\`` `\\` when it becomes a *quote*. This is the POSIX specified behavior anyway: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03